# Apple news publisher failed with Word Press plug-in

Tags: ios, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We recently added "Publish To Apple News" plug-in to our Word Press and getting "Date_Not_Recent" error. After talking to the developers and checking their support pages, it looks like it is a a time zone issue between the WP server (Oregon, US with UTC timezone) and Apple News Publisher (which till this moment Apple can't tell me where it is located, i assume California, but who knows for sure?)

Solution, is to sync those time zones together. My questions:

1- Anyone had any issues rezoning their aws servers?

2- If you had this issue before, what did you do?

I am just trying not fix one thing and break 10 other things in return. just being cautions. We all know that Murphy's law roles in IT.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We figured it out. it was an NTP issue.
We host on AWS, and the time sync packages (NTP) were a little bit out of sync, so we deleted them and installed chrony instead and that worked.
For anyone who is interested, here are the instructions (under configuring the Amazon time sync services):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html